# Dealing with Datasets of rowcount 1

Tags: dataset

I have 2 datasets: dsE and dsF that I want to process in a consistent way:

```
dsE = Dataset[
<|"Col1" -> RandomReal[100], "Col2" ->  RandomReal[100], 
   "Col3" ->  RandomReal[100] 
|>];

dsF = Dataset[{
   <|"Col1" -> RandomReal[100], "Col2" ->  RandomReal[100], 
    "Col3" ->  RandomReal[100] |>,
   <|"Col1" -> RandomReal[100], "Col2" ->  RandomReal[100], 
    "Col3" ->  RandomReal[100] |>
   }];
```

I want to write a function that accepts either dsE or dsF to produce a dataset, say dsG, of the shape

```
Dataset[{
(*1 or more Associations*)
}]
```

Essentially,  WL presents a dataset of 1 row as an Association, whereas datasets of greater than 1 row are presented as a **List** of Associations ~ and I want to make sure that my functions are conforming to exactly the same shape of input data: a List of Associations, regardless of rowsize.

This is proving to be more challenging than I anticipated. I think my approach

```
If[Head@Normal@ds ==  Symbol["Association"], a = Dataset[{ds}], 
  Nothing];
```

...is going down the wrong route for several reasons - this does not handle the generic case of all datasets, does not use the FP approach, etc etc..

Comment: You can declare a dataset with one Association as a list with one element: `dsE = Dataset[{<|"Col1" -> RandomReal[100], "Col2" -> RandomReal[100],
      "Col3" -> RandomReal[100]|>}];`

Comment: Hello @DanielHuber I should have mentioned that I do not have any control over the inputs (dsE,dsF), only the function. Essentially, my function needs to work with a dataset of any rowsize to produce a consistent shape.

Comment: You can check if the head of your data: `dat` is `Dataset`, then it it contains a list, or not, then we need to add the list. This can be done by: `dat= dat /. HoldPattern@Dataset[x__] :> Dataset[{{x}[[1]]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = If[#[Head] === List, #, #[List]] &;

f @ dsE
```

[image]

```
Normal @ f @ dsE
```

> ```
> {<|"Col1" -> 95.2175, "Col2" -> 91.2453, "Col3" -> 99.8906|>}
> ```

```
f @ dsF
```

[image]

```
Normal @ f @ dsF
```

> ```
> {<|"Col1" -> 95.9263, "Col2" -> 32.9574, "Col3" -> 42.4036|>,
>  <|"Col1" -> 25.8791, "Col2" -> 90.6759,   "Col3" -> 95.1289|>}
> ```

Comment: wow, @kglr that's perfect.

Comment: I didn't quite get the intuition for how #[List] works. It appears that you can construct a WL expression to transform anything to any Head (type). Is there any documentation on this? I dont think the syntax guide covers it: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html

Comment: @berrynice, I am using `Head` and `List` as `Query`s. That is, `dsE[Head]` is the same as `Query[Head]@dsE`. Regarding, _"transform **anything** to any..."_, note that _"Query can operate on a Dataset object or an arbitrary nested expression consisting of lists and associations"_.

Comment: understood! thanks a lot @kglr